# div with floating elements 100% height of its content?

Tags: css

Why does my parents div "dad" not take the height of its children? 
http://jsfiddle.net/MeHyJ/

```
<div id="dad">
    <div class="float">1</div>
    <div class="float">2</div>    
    <div class="float">3</div>      
    <div class="float">4</div>  
</div>

#dad {

height:100%;
width:100px;
border:1px solid black;
}
.float {
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` rather than using
`float:left; clear:both;`.

**Task** : Figure out the difference between **display: `block`/`inline`/`inline-block`;**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MeHyJ/2/show/) & [**CODE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MeHyJ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It is a well-known issue of floated elements.
You need so-called clearfix method: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

```
#dad:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

or make a class that you can reuse later in your code:

```
.clrfx:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Your updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MeHyJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the css of id #dad as below:

```
#dad {
float:left;
height:100%;
width:100px;
border:1px solid black;
}
```